# How Httphandler Reusable memory works?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-2

I created a HttpHandler and following is the setting in the Web.config

```
<add verb="*" path="*.png" type="MvcApplication1.Handler2"/>

IsReusable = true in HttHandler
```

Let's say, I have 20 users in my application, which are trying to type the following url

```
http://Domainname/abc.jpg
```

As we all know if `IsReusable = false`, By the Response End, the HandlerRecycleList of HttpApplication will set to null but this is not true in case of following

```
IsReusable = true
```

**Question**

1. HttpHandler memory will be common for all users in case of  when `IsReusable = true`?
2. or let's say I requested the above url and this memory will allocated to me only and next time it will be reused in my case and other users will be allocated HttpHandler memory on Session basis ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the handler is common for all users. It's not tied to any session object.

If you set Reusable to true, the instance will be cached and reused in other requests, just calling its ProcessRequest method over and over, without creating new instances. The handler does not look at the session for this.  The app will create as many handlers as needed to handle the current load.

So if you have 20 users concurrently accesing your app, 20 instances will be created. If, on the other hand, you have 20 users sequentially accessing your handler, only one instance will be (re)used.

You cannot control the amount of instances created, this is done on-demand.

The downside is that if you use a lot of memory in a handler, this will affect negatively the memory usage, since these instances will survive GC cycles.

You also have to make sure that the state at the end of processRequest is valid for the next request.

Comment: I have a query. Thanks for your patience. : When you request a particular page, it's `HttpHandler` gets called ? It's because that page is derived from `HttpHandler` and then the `Page` object is created ? and then the `Page Events` are called? Is it like that ?